# Monthly automatic email to one person

Tags: gmail, automation

I have Gmail.  I need the same email content sent to the same person, at the first of each month.  Is there a way to set that up to happen monthly without having to think about it or do any action?

Comment: This is not something you can do natively in Gmail. You'll need a third-party service.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Boomerang for Gmail](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/l/how-to-send-recurring-emails.html).

You could also connect your Gmail to an Outlook account and use Windows' built-in [Task Scheduler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zO4PnvPGtcs) to send an email through Outlook (from your Gmail account).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com/).

[This recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/101450) will have an email sent on a specific day of the month. You also define the recipient address, the subject, the body of the email message and you can even provide an URL to attach a file.